# using this for second variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use this.value for $(".selector"), $("#style_background") is my save button. When i use this code like this.value is coming 'save', how can i do this dania, seablue.

```
$("#style_background").click(function(){

    if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {

        document.cookie = "background=" + this.value + ";" + "path=/";

    } else {}

});
```

HTML

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" class="selector" id="cookie_dania" name="background" value="dania">
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" class="selector" id="cookie_seablue" name="background" value="seablue">
</li>
```

Comment: *I want to use this.value for $(".selector"), $("#style_background") is my save button.* not very clear

Comment: "background=" + this.value is coming save i want to get $(".selector").value using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the selector with `:checked` value `each` used for select the value of checked radio button one by one.radio button selected only.you need a both checked value use with `checkbox` instead of `radio` button

```js
$("#style_background").click(function() {
  $(".selector:checked").each(function(a){
 // if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {
    //document.cookie = "background=" + $(this).val() + ";" + "path=/";
 // } else {} 
  console.log($(this).val())
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="selector" id="cookie_dania" name="background" value="dania">
</li>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="selector" id="cookie_seablue" name="background" value="seablue">
</li>
<button id="style_background">save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `this` is referring to the `style_background` selector as you have bind click event to it so you need to pass specific selector as

```
$("#style_background").click(function(){

    if ($(".selector").is(":checked")) {

        document.cookie = "background=" + $(".selector:checked").val() + ";" + "path=/";

    } else {}

});
```

Comment: You need to get the value of `checked` selector only